# MySQL Check if Varchar Date is Between String Dates

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL database where I have a field that holds a date like `01/31/2014` and it is of varchar type. Even though I have access to this database changing the structure is off limits as of now.

Is there any way to check if a string date in Javascript is between my varchar type date in the database?

The error I am getting is that when I choose to search for dates between (e.g. `08/31/2013` and `12/31/2013`) it yields the correct query results, however when I search for dates between (e.g. `08/31/2013` and `01/01/2014`) I get no results found from my quest even though there is.

I believe this error is something to do with the date column's structure not being a `DATE`. Is this true and how can I overcome my problem?

Comment: Show your code. We aren't mind readers.

Comment: There's not much code to show you. The question is apparent here. I am wondering if I need my column to be a `DATE` for it to accurately check if it's in between two dates.

Comment: Show us the code that you are using to search. We can't accurately respond to your specific situation when a huge portion of what could be the problem is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL you are looking for I believe is:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column, '%m/%/d/%Y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(column, '%m/%/d/%Y')
AND STR_TO_DATE(column, '%m/%/d/%Y')
```

MySQL has a STR_TO_DATE function, which you can use to parse a string into a date object in MySQL. Then you can use the between keyword for comparison.

My suggestion to you is to store your dates in millisecond format. It will create a lot less confusion and hassle, and it is also a standard across many coding languages. It will also make comparing and converting dates significantly easier.

Comment: The first line would be the column and the next two lines would be my dates? Right now I have this: `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(submittedDate, '%m-%d-%Y') > '08/10/2013' AND STR_TO_DATE(submittedDate, '%m-%d-%Y') < '12/31/2013'`

Comment: The first line is the date you want to check, the second and third are the ones you are comparing against. `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(submittedDate, '%m/%/d/%Y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('08/10/2013', '%m/%/d/%Y')
AND STR_TO_DATE('12/31/2013', '%m/%/d/%Y')`

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column,'%m/%d/%Y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(column,'%m/%d/%Y')
AND STR_TO_DATE(column,'%m/%/d%Y')
```

need to be changed  `'%m/%/d/%Y'` to `'%m/%d/%Y'`