# mySQL - Is it possible to use the BETWEEN clause on a string and have it act as if it was a Date?

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to get a selection from a database based on a start and an end date. I cannot change the field type so i will have to make due with a string value.

The query returns no results, even though there is a matching result:

FieldName: date (string)

FieldValue: 03.03.2015 (string)

```
SELECT * FROM `submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = 'date' AND `FieldValue` BETWEEN '01.01.2015' AND '01.01.2016'
```

How do?

Comment: As it is 2 string, this won't work. For example the string '01.02.2015' is not between your 2 values. Would have worked if you used a `YYYY-mm-dd` format. In that case '2015.02.01' is between '2015.01.01' and '2016.01.01'. (As 'b' is between 'a' and 'c'.)

Comment: Yeah, i am able to change the ordering of the FieldValue, so i could show it yyyy.mm.dd that way it will be between numerically and hence work. But seems a bit hacky, but i might have to end up going that route :)

Comment: Store data properly. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `SELECT STR_TO_DATE();` to convert the string to a date.

```
SELECT * FROM `submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = 'date' AND str_to_date(`FieldValue`, '%d.%m.%Y') BETWEEN str_to_date('01.01.2015', '%d.%m.%Y') AND str_to_date('01.01.2016','%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: I tried using this when i read the advice on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310219/mysql-check-if-varchar-date-is-between-string-dates but it didnt convert correctly

I did the following

SELECT * 
FROM `submission_values` 
WHERE `FieldName` = 'date' 
AND STR_TO_DATE(`FieldName`, '%d.%.m.%Y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01.01.2015', '%d.%.m.%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('01.01.2016', '%d.%.m.%Y')

Comment: @MadsHundhammer Can you show some sample data and the ddl?

Comment: Ill try to paint a more complete picture :)

The database is generated by a form. The form creates two entries upon completion, one entry has:


SubmissionId
FormId
DateSubmitted
UserId
Username
UserId


The second one has:
SubmissionValueId
FormId
SubmissionID
FieldName
FieldValue

I originally tied them together using SQL JOIN and their common SubmissionId and filtered by the submitted date

I now have to use a submitted field that the form saves as a string.

I have tried using all combinations of STR_TO_DATE(), i also tried CAST() to cast the field to my desired type.

Comment: But what is the concrete value of column Fildname? Is it a string if yes in which format?

Comment: Name: FieldName  

Type: text  

Collation: utf8_general_ci

Null: No 

Default: None

Comment: @MadsHundhammer and fieldValue?

Comment: and the value in `FieldValue`is like `01.01.2015`?

Comment: @MadsHundhammer Than the sql in my answer should work. Attention. Have updated my answer

Comment: oh. I didnt notice the change, will try to implement tomorrow when i start work. Thanks alot for the assistance! :D

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch Jens! Auf Wiedersehen!